# I have a variable that is defined and undefined at the same time

Tags: javascript, undefined

I wrote some code for tic-tac-toe in javascript which starts with:

```
var board = [
  [0,0,0],
  [0,0,0],
  [0,0,0]
];
```

(This is declared outside of a function)

And later on when generating the computer move in a function it runs this line of code in a loop:

```
if (board[xx][yy] == 0) {
```

But it gives me the error `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`
(xx is equal to 0).

If I add a `console.log(board)` in the same function and loop before the line giving me the error, it gives me the same error but logs the value of board to the console (after the error).

If I can log the variable, why can't I refer to it in that line?

Here's some code: (I didn't include the HTML which it refers to)

```
var board = [
  [0,0,0],
  [0,0,0],
  [0,0,0]
];

const buttonGrid = [
  [1,2,3],
  [4,5,6],
  [7,8,9]
];

function computerMove() {
  //check for winning move
  xx = -1;

  while (xx < 3) {
    xx ++;
    yy = -1;
    while (yy < 3) {
      yy ++;
      if (board[xx][yy] == 0) {       //line with error
        board[xx][yy] = 2;
        if (checkWin() == 2) {        //checkWin returns the winning player
          toClick = (buttonGrid[xx][yy]).toString(); //
          updateBox(toClick, xx, yy); //confirms move
          return;
        }
        else {
          board[xx][yy] = 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you mark in the code where the error is?

Comment: On which line it gives you that error ?

Comment: That's a lot of code, dude. If you could reproduce the error in a narrowed scope, maybe we could help you better.

Comment: Probably `xx` or `yy` is not what you think it is. You should log that. You should also create a [mcve] instead of showing us all your code (without the HTML that would allow us to actually try it out)

Comment: Your `while`s are wrong. The final iteration of `while (yy < 3) { yy++; }` is an iteration where `yy` is `3`. Same with all of your `xx` loops.

Comment: The problem is that you're incrementing `xx` and `yy` *after* you check whether they're within the array bounds. Use an ordinary `for` loop or the `forEach` function and you won't have this problem.

Comment: You should start iterating at 0 not -1 and increment AFTER your logic not before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following snippet, which is present all throughout your code (for both `yy` and `xx`):

```js
var yy = -1;
while (yy < 3) {
  yy++;
  console.log(yy);
}
```

Notice that the final iteration logs `3`. Your arrays have only three items, therefore trying to access an item at index `3` will return `undefined`.

---

Changing `... < 3` to `... < 2` would solve this issue:

```js
var yy = -1;
while (yy < 2) {
  yy++;
  console.log(yy);
}
```

Or better yet, use a traditional `for` loop:

```js
for (let yy = 0; yy <= 2; yy++) {
  console.log(yy);
}
```